# What´s the most efficient way to store date based availibilites

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-performance

i´m new here and have a project where i have a performance problem that seems hard to fix. I have created a search for objects that have availibilities means a very simple structure:

```
ObjectID | Date | Number of available objects 
---------------------------------------------
Object1  | 01.01.2019 | 1
Object1  | 02.01.2019 | 1
Object1  | 03.01.2019 | 0
Object1  | 04.01.2019 | 1
Object1  | 05.01.2019 | 1
Object2  | 01.01.2019 | 1
Object2  | 02.01.2019 | 1
Object2  | 03.01.2019 | 0
Object2  | 04.01.2019 | 1
Object2  | 05.01.2019 | 1
```

I´m working with mysql and php

A typical query would be:
Which objects are available between 01.01.2019 - 28.02.2019 10 days available in a row.

It´s not really hard to make it working with mysql but once you have more then 10 users using the searchfunction the server load becomes extremly high eventough the table is optimised (indexes etc.) The server has 2 cores with 4 GB of RAM.

I also tried to store the dates comma separated per object in a table and let the application search but that creates extrem high traffic between application and database which is also not a real solution.

In total we have around 20.000 Objects and availabilities stored for max. 500 days so we have around 10.000.000 datasets in my first solution.

Does anybody have and idea what´s the most efficient way toDo this ? 
(How to store it to make search fast ?)

For this project i sadly can not cache the searches.

Thanks for you help and Kind Regards, Christoph

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you to add the search function and where are the indexes in your table (a table definition mockup)? This could help clarify why the high load.

Comment: Don't return all of the objects at once.. return only portions of the query. let the client handle querying for more if the user scrolls down more "I'm not sure if that's how it works".

Answer (score 0):

- Don't store dates in `28.02.2019` format.  Flip it over, then use a `DATE` datatype in the table.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- What is your algorithm for searching?
- The header says "number of objects", yet the values seem to be only 0 or 1, as if it is a boolean flag??
- What is the maximum timespan?  (If under 64, there are bit-oriented tricks we could play.)

By looking at adjacent rows (cf `LAG()`, if using MySQL 8.0), decide when an object *changes* state.  Save *those* dates.

From that, it is one more hop to get "how many consecutive days" starting at one of those dates.  This will be a simple query, and very fast if you have a suitable composite index.